# Gradle sync failed error in android studio3.6

Tags: android, sdk

Gradle sync failed: Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\Anandmayee Maity\AndroidStudioProjects\oops\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
            No value with key 'distributionUrl' specified in wrapper properties file 'C:\Users\Anandmayee Maity\AndroidStudioProjects\oops\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (96 ms)
i am not able to find folder in which  .java and .xml should contain

if anybody have any idea please help it out

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

your gradle-wrapper.properties file should be like this

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip #You must be missing this line in your gradle-wrapper.properties file
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to try uninstalling and installing android studio again.